# Kafka on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, microservices, aws-msk

We have 12 API's deployed on a cluster and we are using Kafka which are deployed on 3 EC2 instances. Should I add the Kafka Servers in K8s too or should I keep it the same? Or should I start using AWS MSK?

Still Experimenting so any suggestions or good documentation would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

This is opinion based so it's probably going to be closed but check out https://strimzi.io/. It's been working great for us.